# Sort a list by an int property in the list differing per entry

Tags: c#, list, sorting, last.fm

I am currently working on a little program for myself, connected to LastFM. Here I can fetch a whole list artists, played in the current week. This is how I first fetch the artists played and store them into a list:

```
WeeklyArtistChart WeeklyArtists = user.GetWeeklyArtistChart();
//WeeklyArtistChart is a list
```

Now, let's say each entry in WeeklyArtists[i].Artist has a property named 'Playcount'. I want to sort my list based on that property in descending order, only problem is, I have no idea how!

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ and [`Enumerable.OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx):

```
var sortedArtists = WeeklyArtists.OrderByDescending(a => a.Artist.Playcount);
```

If you need a copy of the list with this order, you need to call [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
WeeklyArtists = sortedArtists.ToList();
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not clear whether it should be `a.Playcount` or `a.Artist.Playcount`.

Comment: @KirkWoll: You're right, it seems that `Artist` is a property, edited my answer.

Comment: This worked, apologies for being a bit unclear. a.PlayCount was good and worked, and I had to wait before I could mark your post as answer. Thanks!